# Elasticsearch without access to index shows security exception and also shows data for repeat executions

Tags: elasticsearch, security

We are on elastic version 8.8.1, build_flavor is default and build_type is docker. We have created an user user_1 with role role_1 which has access to index_1 and no other index.

We are noticing a security issue that when I login as that user user_1 and try to access index_2 to which it does not have access. When I execute command in dev console multiple times to access the index_2, I get security exception which is fine.

**ISSUE**: But on some attempts it shows the data which should NOT happen. When I execute the command 10 times, ~ 5 times I get security exception error (Correct)  and ~ 5 times I can see the data (Issue) . Has anyone faced this issue? Do we know what is the root cause or any recommendation for next step?

```
GET index_2/_search

security_exception, "reason": "action [indices:data/read/search] is unauthorized for user [user_1] with effective roles [role_1] on indices [index_2], this action is granted by the index privileges [read,all]"
```

The command should always fail with security exception which is not happening always.